# Get the biggest number in database column

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the biggest number in database like in the photo

[image]

For example the biggest number is 31, and the when I click a button it will increment with one. For example if a press button ADD in database it will be added number 32. I want to do it programmatically.

Thank You.

Comment: what tecnology are you using? plain sql server? need a sql command or a linq expression for entityframework?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok dear this is the simple solution

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT (ISNULL(MAX(yourcolumn), 0) + 1) as BigNum FROM yourtable";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
sqlConnection1.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
{
    int bingnum =Convert.ToInt32( reader["BigNum"]);
}
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. I will try it once.

Comment: my skype id is unseendreamzzz , engr.alinisar@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

dear friend in sql server simple you can do this

```
        DECLARE @MaxNum int;
        SELECT @MaxNum  = ISNULL(MAX(yourcolumn), 0) + 1 FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Thank You. But in tags I've added ASP.NET. So I ant it in ASP.NET language. :)
I do not want to edit the database. :)

Comment: dear friend you must have to query you database 1st and then make increment on the last id if you use linq or sql query

Comment: Yes, I know the logic but please can you write a sample code?

Comment: Yes. Code in ASP.NET. :)